# Problems with integrating ui-calendar into angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I m trying to integrate ui-calendar(https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar) into an angular app and getting errors.I generated the structure of the app with yeoman and then tried integrating ui-calendar into the app but i get following errors

```
Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'imagemin-gifsicle'

Running "newer:jshint" (newer) task

Running "newer:jshint:all" (newer) task

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

app/scripts/calendar.js
  line 16   col 7   Missing "use strict" statement.
  line 45   col 18  Strings must use singlequote.
  line 141  col 22  Did you mean to return a conditional instead of an assignment?
  line 172  col 5   Missing "use strict" statement.
  line 12   col 5   'Appointment1App' is defined but never used.
  line 254  col 60  'oldTokens' is defined but never used.
  line 254  col 49  'newTokens' is defined but never used.
  line 262  col 48  'oldO' is defined but never used.
  line 262  col 43  'newO' is defined but never used.

✖ 9 problems

Warning: Task "jshint:all" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

**Here is the code in my controller.js file**

```
var Appointment1App = angular.module('ui.calendar', [])
  .constant('uiCalendarConfig', {})
  .controller('uiCalendarCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){

      var sourceSerialId = 1,
          eventSerialId = 1,
          sources = $scope.eventSources,
          extraEventSignature = $scope.calendarWatchEvent ? $scope.calendarWatchEvent : angular.noop,

          wrapFunctionWithScopeApply = function(functionToWrap){
              var wrapper;

              if (functionToWrap){
                  wrapper = function(){
                      // This happens outside of angular context so we need to wrap it in a timeout which has an implied apply.
                      // In this way the function will be safely executed on the next digest.

                      var args = arguments;
                      var _this = this;
                      $timeout(function(){
                        functionToWrap.apply(_this, args);
                      });
                  };
              }

              return wrapper;
          };

      this.eventsFingerprint = function(e) {
        if (!e.__uiCalId) {
          e.__uiCalId = eventSerialId++;
        }
        // This extracts all the information we need from the event. http://jsperf.com/angular-calendar-events-fingerprint/3
        return "" + e.__uiCalId + (e.id || '') + (e.title || '') + (e.url || '') + (+e.start || '') + (+e.end || '') +
          (e.allDay || '') + (e.className || '') + extraEventSignature(e) || '';
      };

      this.sourcesFingerprint = function(source) {
          return source.__id || (source.__id = sourceSerialId++);
      };

      this.allEvents = function() {
        // return sources.flatten(); but we don't have flatten
        var arraySources = [];
        for (var i = 0, srcLen = sources.length; i < srcLen; i++) {
          var source = sources[i];
          if (angular.isArray(source)) {
            // event source as array
            arraySources.push(source);
          } else if(angular.isObject(source) && angular.isArray(source.events)){
            // event source as object, ie extended form
            var extEvent = {};
            for(var key in source){
              if(key !== '_uiCalId' && key !== 'events'){
                 extEvent[key] = source[key];
              }
            }
            for(var eI = 0;eI < source.events.length;eI++){
              angular.extend(source.events[eI],extEvent);
            }
            arraySources.push(source.events);
          }
        }

        return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arraySources);
      };

      // Track changes in array by assigning id tokens to each element and watching the scope for changes in those tokens
      // arguments:
      //  arraySource array of function that returns array of objects to watch
      //  tokenFn function(object) that returns the token for a given object
      this.changeWatcher = function(arraySource, tokenFn) {
        var self;
        var getTokens = function() {
          var array = angular.isFunction(arraySource) ? arraySource() : arraySource;
          var result = [], token, el;
          for (var i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; i++) {
            el = array[i];
            token = tokenFn(el);
            map[token] = el;
            result.push(token);
          }
          return result;
        };
        // returns elements in that are in a but not in b
        // subtractAsSets([4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 7]) => [6]
        var subtractAsSets = function(a, b) {
          var result = [], inB = {}, i, n;
          for (i = 0, n = b.length; i < n; i++) {
            inB[b[i]] = true;
          }
          for (i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
            if (!inB[a[i]]) {
              result.push(a[i]);
            }
          }
          return result;
        };

        // Map objects to tokens and vice-versa
        var map = {};

        var applyChanges = function(newTokens, oldTokens) {
          var i, n, el, token;
          var replacedTokens = {};
          var removedTokens = subtractAsSets(oldTokens, newTokens);
          for (i = 0, n = removedTokens.length; i < n; i++) {
            var removedToken = removedTokens[i];
            el = map[removedToken];
            delete map[removedToken];
            var newToken = tokenFn(el);
            // if the element wasn't removed but simply got a new token, its old token will be different from the current one
            if (newToken === removedToken) {
              self.onRemoved(el);
            } else {
              replacedTokens[newToken] = removedToken;
              self.onChanged(el);
            }
          }

          var addedTokens = subtractAsSets(newTokens, oldTokens);
          for (i = 0, n = addedTokens.length; i < n; i++) {
            token = addedTokens[i];
            el = map[token];
            if (!replacedTokens[token]) {
              self.onAdded(el);
            }
          }
        };
        return self = {
          subscribe: function(scope, onChanged) {
            scope.$watch(getTokens, function(newTokens, oldTokens) {
              if (!onChanged || onChanged(newTokens, oldTokens) !== false) {
                applyChanges(newTokens, oldTokens);
              }
            }, true);
          },
          onAdded: angular.noop,
          onChanged: angular.noop,
          onRemoved: angular.noop
        };
      };

      this.getFullCalendarConfig = function(calendarSettings, uiCalendarConfig){
          var config = {};

          angular.extend(config, uiCalendarConfig);
          angular.extend(config, calendarSettings);

          angular.forEach(config, function(value,key){
            if (typeof value === 'function'){
              config[key] = wrapFunctionWithScopeApply(config[key]);
            }
          });

          return config;
      };
  }])
  .directive('uiCalendar', ['uiCalendarConfig', '$locale', function(uiCalendarConfig, $locale) {
    // Configure to use locale names by default
    var tValues = function(data) {
      // convert {0: "Jan", 1: "Feb", ...} to ["Jan", "Feb", ...]
      var r, k;
      r = [];
      for (k in data) {
        r[k] = data[k];
      }
      return r;
    };
    var dtf = $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS;
    uiCalendarConfig = angular.extend({
      monthNames: tValues(dtf.MONTH),
      monthNamesShort: tValues(dtf.SHORTMONTH),
      dayNames: tValues(dtf.DAY),
      dayNamesShort: tValues(dtf.SHORTDAY)
    }, uiCalendarConfig || {});

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {eventSources:'=ngModel',calendarWatchEvent: '&'},
      controller: 'uiCalendarCtrl',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, controller) {

        var sources = scope.eventSources,
            sourcesChanged = false,
            eventSourcesWatcher = controller.changeWatcher(sources, controller.sourcesFingerprint),
            eventsWatcher = controller.changeWatcher(controller.allEvents, controller.eventsFingerprint),
            options = null;

        function getOptions(){
          var calendarSettings = attrs.uiCalendar ? scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.uiCalendar) : {},
              fullCalendarConfig;

          fullCalendarConfig = controller.getFullCalendarConfig(calendarSettings, uiCalendarConfig);

          options = { eventSources: sources };
          angular.extend(options, fullCalendarConfig);

          var options2 = {};
          for(var o in options){
            if(o !== 'eventSources'){
              options2[o] = options[o];
            }
          }
          return JSON.stringify(options2);
        }

        scope.destroy = function(){
          if(attrs.calendar) {
            scope.calendar = scope.$parent[attrs.calendar] =  elm.html('');
          } else {
            scope.calendar = elm.html('');
          }
        };

        scope.init = function(){
          scope.calendar.fullCalendar(options);
        };

        eventSourcesWatcher.onAdded = function(source) {
          scope.calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', source);
          sourcesChanged = true;
        };

        eventSourcesWatcher.onRemoved = function(source) {
          scope.calendar.fullCalendar('removeEventSource', source);
          sourcesChanged = true;
        };

        eventsWatcher.onAdded = function(event) {
          scope.calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', event);
        };

        eventsWatcher.onRemoved = function(event) {
          scope.calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(e) { return e === event; });
        };

        eventsWatcher.onChanged = function(event) {
          scope.calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
        };

        eventSourcesWatcher.subscribe(scope);
        eventsWatcher.subscribe(scope, function(newTokens, oldTokens) {
          if (sourcesChanged === true) {
            sourcesChanged = false;
            // prevent incremental updates in this case
            return false;
          }
        });

        scope.$watch(getOptions, function(newO,oldO){
            scope.destroy();
            scope.init();
        });
      }
    };
}]);
```

here is the code in index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="Appointment1App">
  <div ui-calendar ng-model="eventSources"></div>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
          <li class="active"><a ng-href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a ng-href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a ng-href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3 class="text-muted">appointment1</h3>
      </div>

      <div ng-include="'views/main.html'" ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>

      <div class="footer">
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> from the Yeoman team</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
       (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
       m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
       })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/calendar.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you've solve your problem but I found this from their github acct:
https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/521

Basically says you have to replace the jshint:all:src configuration line:

```
'<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
```

with:

```
'<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{**/*}*.js'
```

Worked for me.